# Vector iterator incomptible on loop

Tags: c++, algorithm, search, vector, runtime-error

I have a problem with a loop to search for an Employee in my vector, using auto, for some reason im getting vector iterator incomptible, here is the function:

```
Employee * searchEmp(int id,Company * comp)
{
    for(auto i = comp->getEmployees().begin(); i < comp->getEmployees().end(); ++i)
        if((*i)->getID()==id)
            return (*i);
    return NULL;
}
```

it always collapse with the error on the ++i part.

few notes:

1. Each employee has an id.
2. there is  a 1 item in the list for sure(getEmployees).
3. the loop supposed to go through all the vector and find an employee with the id equal to the id im looking for.

company header:

```
#include "Manager.h"

class Company 
{
public:
    Company();
    Company(string name,string adress,Manager * ceo);
    void companyInfo();
    Manager * ceo;
    vector<Employee *> getEmployees();
    void addEmployee(Employee * worker);
private:
    string name;
    string adress;
    vector<Employee *> employees;

};
```

Comment: Urelated: but In your *for* condition, You probably want to use `i != comp->getEmployees().end()` (note the **`!=`**) rather than `i < comp->getEmployees().end()`

Comment: You should use [smart pointers](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory) instead of all those raw pointers.

Comment: Please post the exact error you are getting.

Comment: You seem to be using a lot of owning pointers. Beyond @user0042's great recommendation, ask yourself rather or not dynamic allocation is really the best solution in each case. Value semantics has many benefits.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Company::getEmployees()` returns by value, that means for `comp->getEmployees().begin()` and `comp->getEmployees().end()`, you'll get two iterators of two different temporary `vector`s which are copied respectively (and will be destroyed immediately with two dangled iterators left), the iterators don't belong to the same one `vector` at all.

If returning by value is your intent, then you should use a named variable, e.g.

```
Employee * searchEmp(int id,Company * comp)
{
    auto v = comp->getEmployees();
    for(auto i = v.begin(); i < v.end(); ++i)
        if((*i)->getID()==id)
            return (*i);
    return NULL;
}
```

or make `getEmployees` returning by reference if possible, .e.g

```
class Company 
{
public:
    ...
    vector<Employee *>& getEmployees();
    ...
};
```

Answer (score 2):

`getEmployees()` return the vector by value.  That means it is a copy, not the actual vector that is stored in the class.  So when you do

```
for(auto i = comp->getEmployees().begin(); i < comp->getEmployees().end(); ++i)
```

The begin and end iterators belong to two different vectors that both go out of scope since they are temporary objects.

To use what you have you need to make `getEmployees()` return a reference to the vector.